# How to resolve error, when implementing Auth Email Verification in laravel?

Tags: laravel, ssl, smtp, laravel-7, email-verification

when implementing email verification Got below mentioned error. Added Auth::routes(['verify' => true]); in **routes/web.php** file and

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth','verified']);
    }.
```

in **HomeController.php** file

Error:

production.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host ******* :stream_socket_client(): Peer certificate CN=`**************' did not match expected CN=`*********' {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Connection could not be established with host ********** :stream_socket_client(): Peer certificate CN=`***************' did not match expected CN=`**************' at /home/hellovcard/public_html/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:261)

**Env file**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=************
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=*********
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=**********
MAIL_FROM_NAME="*******"
```

**config/mail.php**

```
 'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score -2):

update config/mail.php

```
'mailers' => [
    'smtp' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'timeout' => null,
        'auth_mode' => null,
        'stream' => [
        'ssl' => [
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
    ],
    ],
```

i am sure you will got your solution .

Comment: Downvoted because you essentially recommend to disable certificate validation without pointing out the security implications of it. Disabling certificate validation means that active man in the middle attacks which sniff and modify the traffic are possible, which is  what TLS is supposed to prevent.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i have answered the only solution of problem and nothing .

Comment: *"i have answered **the only solution** of problem and nothing"* - you have answered with the only solution **you are aware of** w/o pointing out the serious security problems of it.